# Newtonsoft.Json many projects targeting different .net frameworks

Tags: c#, reference

- Bar.Core -> .NET Framework 2.0, installed package Newtonsoft.Json for net20.
- Bar.Desktop -> NET Framework 4.5, installed package Newtonsoft.Json for net45, and also references Bar.Core

Result: cannot build Bar.Desktop, since

Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: {the other project}

Found also a warning:

Found conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Comment: The question is kind of vague.
However, when I get the exceeded retry count error, I usually just close visual studio completely, delete the bin folder manually, re-open visual studio, and build again.
If you find you can't delete the bin folder manually, then something outside of visual studio has a lock on it (usually either file explorer or the command prompt if you're in that directory, or if the built application didn't fully shut down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior you are experiencing is totally unrelated to the version of nuget package you have. What the `Exceeded retry count of 10.` exception is telling you, is that the project you are trying to build is still in use, and therefore can not 'change' the files

If you have several instances of visual studio open, be sure you are not debugging the same project. If not, search for your project inside your task manager, and terminate the executable. Afterwords you should be able to build again.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing Visual Studio, cleaning your bin/obj folders, restarting in admin mode (run as Administrator), and then do a Rebuild.

Sometimes debug sessions can cause this sort of behavior, the referencing of two separate Newtonsoft versions shouldn't cause this.

If the above doesn't work, try ensuring that your DLL physical files for the specific versions are fully separated and referenced separately.